# Not able to install cordova Error like permission denied

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to install cordova with  `npm install -g cordova` in my ubuntu (15.10), but getting the following error

```
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/home/gopi/.npm/_locks/cordova-fa12e2e096426a32.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /home/gopi/.npm/_locks/cordova-fa12e2e096426a32.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/gopi/.npm/_locks/cordova-fa12e2e096426a32.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/home/gopi/.npm/_locks/cordova-fa12e2e096426a32.lock' }
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/gopi/npm-debug.log
```

I when i am trying to give `ionic build android` i am getting this error and also when i try `cordova -v` to check the current version i get the same error.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                      ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/gopi/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:352:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
    at checkForUpdates (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:64:20)
    at cli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:116:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:41:1)
```

does any one have idea why the permission is denied, I also tried with sudo `npm install -g cordova`  but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permission problem, try:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm"
```

Comment: @rbumier after trying your code i am faceing the same issues